# JAPANESE LANGUAGE METAに7ページ目がありません?

Tags: help

いつの間にか JAPANESE LANGUAGE METAに迷い込んでしまった時のこと、ふと見ると7ページ目がありません。

なぜでしょうか?

スクリーンショット
https://ibb.co/F6Z0rPr